# Java Programming , Type Casting

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I wrote a method in a class and I wanted to cast an int array div 26 to pass it to a frequency table that is double . Then that kind of error occurred . Can somebody help me please , I am just a student...?

Thanks

```
public void frequency(int[] count ,double [] Q){
        for(double arguments : Q){
            Q[arguments]=(double)(count[arguments]/26);
        }
    }



Encryption.java:35: error: possible loss of precision
            Q[arguments]=(double)(count[arguments]/26);
              ^
  required: int
  found:    double
Encryption.java:35: error: possible loss of precision
            Q[arguments]=(double)(count[arguments]/26);
                                        ^
  required: int
  found:    double
```

Comment: Accessing Arrays viva Index should be done per Integer as you do not have Q[3.5]

Comment: You should use a regular for loop and index into `Q`.

Comment: Ehhh thank you really , it is a stupid one but I am a student and I am just learning to program in java and I have many mistakes to make to learn , thank you though ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the array index with `double` value, which is incorrect, arrays will only contain indexes like 0,1,2, etc...

Also, you will not be able to use **for each** loop to iterate through index, so instead use normal `for` loop as shown below:

```
for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++){
        Q[i]=(double)(count[i]/26);
}
```

Comment: I did not get your point 'ordered set' ? Where did OP mentioned it ?

Comment: Ehhh thank you really , it is a stupid one but I am a student and I am just learning to program in java and I have many mistakes to make to learn , thank you though ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are using double as index of an array which is not possible as index are bound to be int primitive type, that is why you are getting compilation error.

Comment: Ehhh thank you really , it is a stupid one but I am a student and I am just learning to program in java and I have many mistakes to make to learn , thank you though ^^